# summation in sql

Tags: sql

I have a query result [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wYKT.png)[table of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhh9n.png)  i would like to sum the bill amount such that it returns one row with a distinct account ,balance,sum billed amount fPreviousReading,
fCurrentReading,
fConsumption .

result should be

```
1.account 11074 
2.balance269.49
3.sumbilledamount 520.48
4. fPreviousReading 574 
5 fCurrentReading 612 
6 fConsumption 38
```

---

Thanks

query

```
select 
    Ten.Account,
    ten.DCBalance AS Balance,   
    SUM(T.fInclusiveAmount)AS BilledAmount,  
    MRD.fPreviousReading,    
    MRD.fCurrentReading , 
    MRD.fConsumption ,  
    T.cDescription 
    from _mtblTransactions T 
    left join _mtblProperties P ON P.idProperty = T.iPropertyID
    left join _mtblPropertyPortions PP ON PP.idPropertyPortions = T.iPortionID
    left join _mtblPropertyPortionServices PPS ON PPS.idPropertyPortionServices = T.iPropertyPortionServiceID
    left join _mtblCategories Cat ON Cat.idCategory = PP.iPortionUsageID        
    left join _mtblServices S ON PPS.iPortionServiceID = S.idService        
    left join _mtblServiceGroups SG ON S.iServiceGroupID = SG.idServiceGroup        
    left join _mtblRateTariffs RT ON RT.idRateTariffs = PPS.iServiceRateTariffID        
    left join Client Ten ON T.iCustomerID = Ten.DCLink  
    left join _mtblMeters M ON PPS.iPropertyPortionMeterID = M.idMeter      
    left join _mtblWalkDetails WD ON WD.iWalkMeterID = PPS.iPropertyPortionMeterID     
    left join _mtblWalks W ON WD.iWalkID = W.idWalk    
    left join Client Own ON P.iPropertyOwnerID = Own.DCLink
    left outer join _mtblRegions R on R.idRegions = P.iPropertyRegionID   
    left outer join _mtblSubRegions SR on SR.idSubRegions = P.iPropertySubRegionID   
    left outer join _mtblAreas A on A.idAreas = P.iPropertyAreaID   
    left join _etblPeriod PER ON T.iPeriodID = PER.idPeriod    
    left join _mtblMeterReadingDetails MRD ON T.iMeterID = MRD.iMeterReadingsMeterID and T.iPeriodID = MRD.iBillingPeriodID 
    and MRD.iReadingType=0  

    Where 
    oWN.Account='11074'
    and idPeriod='79'
        GROUP BY Ten.Account,ten.DCBalance,MRD.fPreviousReading,   MRD.fCurrentReading,   MRD.fConsumption,   T.cDescription
```

Comment: What are you getting back from the above and how does it differ from what you want

Comment: Without seeing what you are getting out, i'm not 100% sure what would need to be done but would imagine some of the other columns would need aggregate functions applied to them perhaps. As an aside why do you start using 'left outer join' then revert back to just 'left join'?

Comment: Replace WHERE with AND, to get LEFT JOIN result. Also consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: hi all,What am getting is the result in the picture attached

Comment: Click on table of result  in first line of question it will show the result am getting

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know your data, there is a possibility I wrote you a code that would return some double rows. But that is a problem you can easily handle.

Try it, nevertheless:

```
SELECT t1.Account,
       t1.Balance,
       t1.BilledAmount,
       t1.fPreviousReading,
       t1.fCurrentReading,
       t1.fConsumption,
       t2.cDescription
  FROM (SELECT Ten.Account,
               ten.DCBalance AS Balance,
               SUM (T.fInclusiveAmount) AS BilledAmount,
               SUM (MRD.fPreviousReading) AS fPreviousReading,
               SUM (MRD.fCurrentReading) AS fCurrentReading,
               SUM (MRD.fConsumption) AS fConsumption
          FROM      _mtblTransactions T
            left join _mtblProperties P ON P.idProperty = T.iPropertyID
            left join Client Ten ON T.iCustomerID = Ten.DCLink
            left join Client Own ON P.iPropertyOwnerID = Own.DCLink AND oWN.Account='11074'
            left join _etblPeriod PER ON T.iPeriodID = PER.idPeriod
            left join _mtblMeterReadingDetails MRD ON T.iMeterID = MRD.iMeterReadingsMeterID and T.iPeriodID = MRD.iBillingPeriodID
            and MRD.iReadingType=0
            and idPeriod='79'
                GROUP BY Ten.Account,ten.DCBalance) t1
  JOIN (SELECT T.cDescription,
               Ten.Account,
               ten.DCBalance
          FROM      _mtblTransactions T
            left join Client Ten ON T.iCustomerID = Ten.DCLink) t2 ON t2.Account = t1.Account AND t2.DCBalance = t1.DCBalance
```